# How Do I Get DNS Server IP Address In NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a project and stuck in the DNS Leak Tool, where I would have to perform the same task as http://dnsleak.com/ these website doing, is there any logic, where I can get fetch DNS server IP?

Really appreciate if you guys can help!

Regards,
Finn

Comment: Congrats on your first question! If you're new here, you may want to have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. We usually expect people to explain what they have tried, even if it didn't work. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers. You can use this [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) in order to make sure your question is not missing anything important.

Answer (score 5):

I think you just have to do something like this :

```
const dns = require('dns');

dns.getServers();
```

See  [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_getservers) for more information.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have already used this one, and by this, I'm getting my wifi router DNS IP address, when I switched to LAN then It will work perfectly.

But I can not resolve this one with WIFI connection.